# How to handle Lightbox with Capybara, Selenium and Cucumber framework?

Tags: selenium, cucumber, capybara

I'm trying to run a test suite that will handle the jQuery lightbox. Lightbox contains a textarea and a submit button. Before lightbox appears both of these fields are hidden.

But Selenium doesn't understand the visibility of these element in lightbox. It just shows following error.

```
And I fill comment box with "Text !!" # features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:333
  Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::ElementNotVisibleError)
  [remote server] file:///tmp/webdriver-profile20120403-6182-1rd9z23/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command_processor.js:9509:in `unknown'
  [remote server] file:///tmp/webdriver-profile20120403-6182-1rd9z23/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command_processor.js:10510:in `unknown'
  [remote server] file:///tmp/webdriver-profile20120403-6182-1rd9z23/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command_processor.js:10529:in `unknown'
  [remote server] file:///tmp/webdriver-profile20120403-6182-1rd9z23/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command_processor.js:10534:in `unknown'
  [remote server] file:///tmp/webdriver-profile20120403-6182-1rd9z23/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command_processor.js:10482:in `unknown'
  (eval):2:in `send'
  (eval):2:in `fill_in'
  ./features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:335:in `/^I fill comment box with "([^"]*)"$/'
  features/courses_flow.feature:21:in `And I fill comment box with "Text !!"'
```

Comment: Some frameworks make actually _two_ elements which are essentially the same. The first, hidden one, and the second which is or is not there. Use Firebug (and Firefinder?) to look for all the elements that Selenium could find. If it is there, you need to improve your search, or find all complying elements and filter out those invisible ones...

Comment: Thanks for your reply Slanec, but I am trying to figure out some way to access elements in light box which are initially hidden and visible after light box appears.

Comment: Those should be visible for the WebDriver. Are you using the original Lightbox2, or some derivative? Which Selenium version? Could you please provide a simple testcase?

Comment: Thanks Slanec, but Im newbie to cucumber & selenium and I don't know Lightbox2 is what.
Im using selenium version 2.20.0

These are the test cases Im bothering about  

And I fill comment box with "Text !!"  
And I press "submit"  

    When /^(?:|I )fill in "([^"]*)" with "([^"]*)"$/ do |field, value|  
  fill_in(field, :with => value)  
end

Comment: I think Slanec, you were pushing me in right direction, I just not understood your way. Do you want to say Light-box actually creates a new elements which are not hidden??
But with firepath and xpath checker I can see only one !!

Comment: It was one possibility, yes. Some frameworks act that way. It's actually strange that WebDriver thinks those Lightbox elements are not visible. Anyway, I am happy to see your problem resolved!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a temporary workaround you can allow capybara see hidden elements. I suggest use it with caution and add a special tag and enable it only for certain scenarios:

```
Before('@ignore-hidden-elements') do
  Capybara.ignore_hidden_elements = true
end
```

Comment: Thanks iafonov for the reply, but Im newbie to cucumber, will you please explain me where should I put this code ??

Comment: you should put it to env.rb, and add @ignore-hidden-elements tag to scenario

Comment: Thanks iafonov for your help, your solution worked in my case...
You saved my lot of time. Can you pls explain how this worked, I just wondering about this solution ...?